# wildfly changes schemaLocation in wsdl to secure url on deploy

Tags: web-services, jboss, wsdl, wildfly

Good morning,

Have a strange problem and have no idea where I should change such behavior. Wildfly 8.2. changes schemaLocation in published wsdl to secure url on deploy. My service port bound to http://hostname:8080/, but schemaLocation changed to https://hostname:8443/service. And I could not find where I have to make changes. Any chance to rewrite schemaLocation to default http port (http://hostname:8080/service)? I use stanalone configuration.

Arman

Comment: Http://hostname:8080 is normally used to serve web page requests. It is not recommended that you deploy web-services on this port. Also it is better to run web-services via a secure protocol such as HTTPS the reason is that SOAP services are communicating in XML which when running HTTP is unsecure. Could you please post a copy of the WSDL you are using?

Comment: Good evening, I'm not sure that wsdl directly impacts, probably http is rewritten in schemaLocation on Wildfly deploy, I'd check with hostname. And found that if I change hostname and according record in dns then it changes hostname in schemaLocation on deploy. After that I tried to play with web services in standalone.xml without any results. And still webservice available with both and http and https, but schemaLocation still with https prefix. Do you know some configuration lines which could help to change default handling?